# How to get PID from remote executed command?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, ssh

If I do the following in Bash, then I get the PID of the remotely started `mbuffer`, and even though `mbuffer` is still running, I get the terminal back, which is what I want.

```
read -r pid < <(ssh 10.10.10.47 'nohup /opt/omni/bin/mbuffer -4 -s 128k -m 2G -v 0 -q -I 8023 >/tmp/mtest </dev/null 2>/tmp/mtest.err & echo $!')

echo $pid
```

Now I would like to do the same in Perl, so I try

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
    system("read -r pid < <(ssh 10.10.10.47 'nohup /opt/omni/bin/mbuffer -4 -s 128k -m 2G -v 0 -q -I 8023 >/tmp/mtest </dev/null 2>/tmp/mtest.err & echo $!'); echo \$pid");
};

print "stdout $stdout\n";
print "stderr $stderr\n";
print "exit   $exit\n";
```

Here I would have expected that `$stdout` would have given me the PID from the last `echo` command, but I got nothing.

**Question**

How do I get the PID of the remotely executed `mbuffer` in Perl, and so the Perl script isn't waiting for `mbuffer` to exit before continuing?

Comment: I would advise not using double quotes for your system command, but to instead use single quotes with an alternative delimiter such as `q{}`.  You escaped your `\$pid`, but you failed to escape `$!`.  It's therefore possible that an error is being reported but not displayed to you.

Comment: Very nice spotted. I can't make `q{}` work inside `system()`. It is ignored it seams.

Comment: How could someone dislike this question. +1 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seams to be that it is not possible to execute two commands in one `system()` or maybe it is, but not possible to get the output from the last command.

Creating a local *helper* script solved the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Redirection of stdin and stderr to files (preventing them from holding
# handles that connect, eventually, to the terminal).

read -r pid < <(ssh $1 "/usr/gnu/bin/nohup /opt/omni/bin/mbuffer -4 -s 128k -m 2G -v 0 -q -I 8023 >/tmp/mtest$2 </dev/null 2>/tmp/mtest.err & echo \$!")

echo $pid
```

and in Perl

```
my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
     system("/comp/mbuffer-zfs-listen.sh 10.10.10.47 11");
};
```

Comment: Anyhow your solution is the better one as `system()` uses `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash` that some of your command features like process substitution may not work. Changing the value of env. variable `SHELL` to `/bin/sh` doesn't help as well.